# Django - Update a foreing key relation

Tags: django, foreign-keys, serialization

I'm having problems with a basic usage on Django (my first time). I'm writing an arcade manager, having Games and Cores(Emulators), that means I have a core field in games.

This is the model file :

```
class Core(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    bios = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Core {}'.format(self.pk)


class Game(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    path = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField()
    logo = models.FileField(blank=True, null=True, upload_to="games/logos/")
    is_archived = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    core = models.ForeignKey(Core, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name="games", default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

This is the views (maybe not interesting):

```
class CoreViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = CoreSerializer
    queryset = Core.objects.all()
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    


class GameViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = GameSerializer
    queryset = Game.objects.filter(is_archived=False)
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
```

And this is the serializers:

```
class CoreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Core
        fields = '__all__'

class GameSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    nb_terminals = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    total_donations = serializers.ReadOnlyField()
    core = CoreSerializer(many=False, read_only=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Game
        fields = '__all__'
```

For the moment I can create, change and remove cores from the database but modifying a game's core (foreing key) is impossible and I dont know why. I will only change if I use

```
core = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Core.objects.all(), many=False)
```

But then the core is only an id and not a serialized object, not what i want for other reasons.

My question is : What's wrong with this, why is my core field not updating from the games's form?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out i am missing the update form data somewhere, but i dont know where.
I added this method to the GameSerializer but validated data contains only the fields {'name': 'a', 'path': 'a', 'description': 'a', 'is_archived': False} without core_id

```
def update(self, instance, validated_data):
    print(validated_data)
    instance.core.id = validated_data.pop("core_id")
    return instance
```

The form looks like this:

```
edit: function() {
  if (this.game) {
    let form = new FormData();
    form.append("name", this.game.name);
    form.append("path", this.game.path);
    form.append("description", this.game.description);
    form.append("core_id", this.selectedCore.id);
    
    this.$http
      .put("game/" + this.$route.params.id + "/", form)
      .then(resp => {
        this.game = resp.data;
        this.$router.push("/games");
      });
  }
}
```

I dont understand why I dont have exactly the same fields in form and validated_data